# Serverless Framework sls Conflicts with Powershell sls (Select-string)

Tags: node.js, powershell, serverless-framework

I installed the Serverless Framework using the following NPM command

```
npm install -g serverless
```

When I try to run the serverless command `sls` in Powershell, I get a strange result which mentions "cmdlet Select-string".

```
sls --version
```

[image]

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: simple: run from command prompt... instead of powershell

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It seems that PowerShell has a command/cmdlet called Select-String which has an alias of sls.  The PowerShell alias sls seems to take precedence over the node.js serverless command of sls.

One way to remove the PowerShell sls alias is by running the following in PowerShell

```
Remove-Item alias:sls
```

This change only applies to the current PowerShell session.

To permanently the sls PowerShell alias, you can change Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file.

From PowerShell open your profile page in Notepad with the following command:

```
notepad $profile
```

Add the following to the file and save.

```
remove-item alias:sls
```

The profile can be reloaded by running the following from Powershell

```
. $profile
```

In my file, you will see that I have removed the aliases of curl and sls.

[image: Change PowerShell Profile]

Now I see what I expect when entering sls in PowerShell.
[image]

[How do I permanently remove a default Powershell alias?](https://superuser.com/a/890193/114570)

**--- Update ----**

A more simple option is to use the command "serverless" instead of "sls".

Comment: For future reference, [aliases *always* takes precedence when powershell tries to resolve unqualified command names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence)

Comment: @Mathias - Thanks for the link.  It's good to know the about command precedence.

Comment: I faced the same issue and this worked for me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For future visitors - in current version (if `serverless` is installed by `npm/yarn`) `^1.61` there is a secondary shortcut option:

```
slss
```

and that shortcut works flawlessly in Powershell. Imo it's the simplest way to avoid problems with `Select-String` alias collision and do not require any change in Powershell session or config.

```
PS C:\htdocs\serverless> slss -v
Framework Core: 1.61.1
Plugin: 3.2.7
SDK: 2.2.1
Components Core: 1.1.2
Components CLI: 1.4.0
```

If `serverless` is installed by `chocolatey` (as mentioned by @Nick Cox in comment) `slss` approach will fail, and you can use approach suggested by him - `sls.exe`

Comment: For future visitors: note that the chocolatey install doesn't appear to have this alias as of 1.61.

If you installed via chocolatey, an alternative is to invoke `sls.exe` rather than just `sls`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by using [Chocolaty](https://chocolatey.org/).

Instead of `npm install serverless` use `choco install serverless` for windows,

Ref: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/getting-started/